# apache mod_rewrite - simple rewrite of GET-var

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I have a simple problem:

I have a php-file which gets a $_GET-var - something like

```
product.php?a=12
```

and I would like to see and call

```
product12.php
```

in the browser, but I am unable to find an example that deals with this, and I hope very much that someone can take a minute to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my solution works now - for anyone who has a similar problem:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^product(([0-9])+)\.php$ /product.php?a=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```